# App design when using NDK (JNI)

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

As is known to all, we use NDK (or JNI) for invoking native code from Java code.

In my opinion, the JNI layer is just for communicating between Java code and native code. So, we should not put too much code in the JNI layer. Instead, we can put the majority of functionality (Business logic) into the native code (e.g., a shared c library that can be invoked by JNI layer).

However, when I check some opensource projects, most of them put all their business logic in the JNI layer. Is it a good design?

In contrast, should we make the JNI layer just a simple wrapper layer, and put the business logic into the native code layer (e.g., a shared lib for invoking by JNI layer)?

To sum up: 
there are two different designs:

1) Java code --> JNI code (business logic is here)

2) Java code --> JNI code (wrapper layer) --> native code (a shared lib, business logic is here)

Which one is the good design?

I was wondering what is the good design when using the JNI or Android NDK?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends a bit on the nature of your native code. If it is mostly portable, and you keep your JNI code to just a simple wrapper layer, you make it easier to reuse your native code in other applications that are not written in Java.

Comment: @Michael yes, you're right. I mean, for the design perspective, should we make the native code portable and keep the JNI code as a wrapper layer?

Comment: Was that a question? If you _can_ make the code portable without jumping through too many hoops, I don't see why you wouldn't.

Comment: I strongly recommend [this article](http://videocortex.io/2017/salami-method/) where [Adi Shavit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135862/adi-shavit) lays out the best practices of separation of concerns when cross-language interfaces like JNI may be involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's correct to call it *JNI code* and *native code*. What you call "JNI code" is the same native code as any other, it's simply making use of methods and classes defined in the JNI library. After all the Android Runtime itself is written in C/C++, so JNI is just an interface to it.

Now to your question.

From **performance** considerations it is usually best to decouple your logic from JNI, because it incures some extra overhead. E.g. it is more efficient to use `const char *` rather than `jstring` if your string is not supposed to cross the native/managed boundary. Generally don't use JNI types for variables that won't cross the boundary.

From **design** point of view it is also normally best to define your interface separately from logic because it allows to easily change one while not changing another. The same principle as why you're encouraged to use `interface` rather then `class` when possible in Java. But in addition there is also portability of your code at stake.

The only case I can see where it would be reasonable to put all the code in the files making use of JNI, is very small native components that don't really include any complex logic. Like a simple native function verifying a license number or a password.

Answer (score 0):

for safety，the key magics should be putted in the NDK layer.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer to the question. Also, placing information in native code doesn't really add any security.

Comment: communicating between Java code and native code just is the appearance,the core idea of course is improve the reuse of the key magic,and reduce cost of development work on deferent platform.And native code improve the cost of cracking to the application to be exact.